# How to update iOS5 beta 7?

Tags: upgrade, ios

I've got iOS 5 beta 7 on my device (I installed the first beta in June and then updated it a few times wirelessly without any problems) and now, when the final version of the iOS was released, if I'm checking for software update in the device setting it says that my version is up to date which doesn't look as true. 
Thus I'm wondering if I can update my device without resetting OS version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Discussion of beta and pre-release software is off-topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade a beta device to the final GM release. You need to restore the device with final public iOS 5 release.

Comment: Thanks. I presumed something like this but wasn't sure.